# How to add multiple objects to a module UI in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, module

I'm learning how to use modules, and I'd like to render multiple objects in the same module `ui`, sort of like you do in the Shiny main `ui` section using `fluidPage()` for example where you separate the various rendered elements with commas. Is it possible to render multiple objects in the same module's `ui`, as I try doing in the code posting at the bottom? In the rendered Shiny window, I'm trying to insert the value of the slider input after the `mod1` table by using the commented-out lines in the below code. If I uncomment those lines and run the code, the value of the slider input appears but the `mod1` table disappears. I'd like both the table and the value of the slider input to render, for both the `mod1` (the second table rendered in the Shiny window, which is generated by module 1) and the `mod2` (the 3rd table rendered in the Shiny window, which is generated by module 2) tables.

So, how does one render multiple objects in a module `ui`? Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

The below image shows what I'm trying to do, for the sake of learning:

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mod1_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
    # uiOutput(ns("svc")) 
}

mod1_server <- function(id, common) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    new_dat <- reactive({
      df <- common$df
      svc <- common$svc()
      df * as.numeric(svc)
    })
    observe({common$mod1_dat <- new_dat()})
    output$tbl <- renderDT({new_dat()})
    # output$svc <- renderPrint(common$svc()) 
  })
}

mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

mod2_server <- function(id, common) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      dat <- data.frame(common$mod1_dat + 10) 
      common$mod2_table <- dat
      dat
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h5(strong("Base table:")),
    DTOutput("table"),
    sliderInput("svc", "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    mod1_ui("mod1"),
    mod2_ui("mod2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  baseDF <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4) # keep this outside of a reactive
  
  common <- reactiveValues(df = baseDF)
  
  observeEvent(input$svc, {
    common$df <- common$df * input$svc
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(common$df)})
  common$svc <- reactive(input$svc)
  mod1_server("mod1", common)
  mod2_server("mod2", common)
  
  observe({common_tmp <<- shiny::reactiveValuesToList(common)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return more than one HTML element in your `ui` function, put them in a list. For example

```
mod1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(
    DTOutput(ns("tbl")),
    uiOutput(ns("svc"))
  )
}
```

Otherwise only the last value from the last expression evaluated is returned. The `*Output` function do not run with side effects. They return objects that essentially are transformed into HTML.